# ArcPy progessor not progressing?

Tags: arcpy, progress

I have a script too that works fine, but the progressor is not counting up at all (staying at "0%") when I run my tool, even though I can confirm it is working - I can see the products of the script being output.

How do I get it to count up to show progress?

```
fc= str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0)) 

# Set the progressor
arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "doing stuff...", 0 , count, 1)


for row in cursor:
    try:
        do stuff with fc
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: You need to use `SetProgressorPosition()`. The documentation has examples.

Comment: Added that at end of my for loop.  works great now. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've initialized the Progressor, but aren't updating it at each step along the way, as described in the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/setprogressorposition.htm). The parameter is optional, but I prefer to provide explicit step status, in case some steps get skipped.

You're also using *old-style* Cursors, which is a mistake at this point, and the `GetParameterAsText` should start at zero, so I've updated the script...

```
fc = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))

count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0)) 

# Set the progressor
arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "doing stuff...", 0 , count, 1)

i = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["field1","shape@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            # do stuff with row[0] (field1) or row[1] (Geometry)
            pass
        except:
            print arcpy.GetMessages()

        i += 1
        arcpy.SetProgressorPosition(i)

arcpy.ResetProgressor()
```

`arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()` can also capture a Cancel button press (at least, in a Python tool -- `.pyt`), in which case you'd need to wrap that in a try/except block as well.